# Help with Functions in Discrete Mathematics

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

I am having trouble solving this problem:

let $p$ be a positive prime number and let $f:Z_p -> Z_p$ be defined as $f([x])=[x^2]$. Show that $f$ is a function. Give examples of how it is not necessarily injective or surjective.

Work: I know that for a relation to be a function, it has to meet two criteria. However, I have trouble proving that for every $x$ there exists a $y$ such that $f(x)=y$. Putting integer modulo makes this question even harder and I do not know where to start.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're supposed to show here is that $f$ is *well-defined*. Very often, it's pretty obvious whether a function definition fullfills that - if, from example, it's a valid combination of other well-defined functions, it's automatically well-defined.

But if you're dealing with residue classes, things are often not so obvious. In your case, you're dealing with the field $\mathbb{Z}_p = \mathbb{Z} / I$ where $I = p\mathbb{Z}$ of residue classes, i.e. $$
  \mathbb{Z}_p = \{[x] \,:\, x \in \mathbb{Z}\} \text{ where } [x] = \{y \in \mathbb{Z} \,:\, x -y \mid p\} \text{.}
$$
Note that *different* $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ create the *same* residue class $[x]$ - as they must, since you know that $\mathbb{Z}_p$ contains only $p$ elements, where as $\mathbb{Z}$ contains countably many. In the expression $[x]$, $x$ is called a *representative* of the residue class - but that representative, per the previous sentence, is *not* unique. Thus, if you define a function on a set of residue classes in terms of *representatives*, you're at risk of producing a non-well-defined functions. Say for example, you define $$
  f\,:\, \mathbb{Z}_2 \to \mathbb{Z} \,:\, [x] \to x \text{ .}
$$
Now, $0$ and $2$ are members of the *same* residue class in $\mathbb{Z}_2$, i.e. $[0] = [2]$. In other words, there aren't to *distinct* elements $[0]$ and $[2]$ in $\mathbb{Z}_2$, there's only *one* element $[0] = [2]$ with two different *names*. But your definition attempts to map $[0]$ to $0$ and $[2]$ to $2$, which comes down to mapping *one* element to *two* different values.

Thus, for functions defined on sets of residue classes, if the function is defined in terms of *representatives*, you need to show that the result of the function is independent from the particular *choice* of representative. For example, $$
  f\,:\, \mathbb{Z}_2 \to \mathbb{Z} \,:\, [x] \to \begin{cases}
    1 &\text{if $x$ is even} \\
   -1 &\text{if $x$ is odd.}
  \end{cases}
$$
is fine, because you can easily prove that if $x,y$ are *two* representatives of the *same* residue class, then either *both* are even or *both* are odd, so it doesn't matter which one you pick to compute $f$.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your reply. I know the danger of non well-defined functions, but I am still confused. Sorry, I just started learning both integer modulo and functions in my class, so all of this is really new to me.

Comment: So I found another way to do it I think. Basically, to show that it is well-defined, I need to show that if $[a] \equiv [b]$, then $f([a]) \equiv f([b])$. So through this, I showed that if $p|a-b$ then $a-b=pk$ and then $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)=pk(a+b)=p(ka+kb)$. Since $ka+kb$ is an integer, then $p|a^2-b^2$ which means $a^2\equiv b^2$ thus $a^2=b^2$. I don't know if this is right, but this is how my textbook approached a similar problem.

Comment: @Froggy Sounds fine.

Comment: @Froggy But this is exactly what I suggest you do, no? Show that the value $f([x])$ depends only on the residue class, not on the representative. Which you have done nicely, btw.

Comment: Thank you! Now I know how to do these types of problems :)